# Field derivatives in FeynCalc

Tags: physics, feyncalc

I am using the latest version of both Mathematica and FeynCalc. I'm trying to obtain the Feynman rules for a theory with derivative interactions. Following https://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/QuantumField/index.html, I try to define $\partial_\mu \phi$ with `QuantumField[PartialD[\[Mu]],\[Phi]]`. Instead of the expected output, I get $PartialD[\mu]^\phi$. I can't seem to find this issue described anywhere and so I'm quite puzzled as to why this is happening

Comment: `PartialD` is obsolete, use `FCPartialD`; And, read the latest FeynCalc documentations, which can be found in help center.